# Make screensize rules with css or render components based on screen size?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm currently learning React so I dont know which is the best way to make webs responsive, I'm using Semantic UI React as CSS Library.
I'm having some problems when displaying on mobile, but on desktop works perfectly.

The question is basically the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use CSS media instead to simply modify what you need.

Creating extra components depending on the size seems to me to be too much of a solution, although it can be useful in some cases.

From my point of view I can only advise you to add simple rules in CSS.